# Basic Integration: Evaluating the Lower Sum and the Limit of the Lower Sum as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, riemann-sum

I know this is a basic integration question, but I am just beginning to learn the subject and don't fully understand it yet - which is why I don't know the answer to this question.
**The question is:**
For $f(x) = x^{2}$, divide the interval [0,2] into $n$ equally-wide subintervals and evaluate the lower sum and the limit of the lower sum as $ n \rightarrow \infty$.

I know that if $ n \rightarrow \infty$ then I am taking the limit of the Riemann Sum - or using the integral. But, how would I solve this problem step by step?

Comment: See https://www3.nd.edu/~nancy/Math10350/riemannsum.pdf for a calculation and http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannSum.html for visualization.

Comment: I think you meant $n$ instead of $x$ in the title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a Riemann Sum (With Right Endpoints):

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}(\frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nf(a +i(\frac{b-a}{n})))$$
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}(\frac{2}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(i(\frac{2}{n}))^2)$$
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}(\frac{2}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(\frac{4i^2}{n^2}))$$
Factor out the constants
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}(\frac{8}{n^3}\sum_{i=1}^n(i^2))$$
Using the summation property of $i^2$
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}(\frac{8}{n^3}(\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}))$$
Distribute the n
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}(\frac{8}{n^3}(\frac{(2n^3+3n^2+n)}{6}))$$
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}(\frac{8(2n^3+3n^2+n)}{6n^3})$$
Because this limit tends to infinity, we look at the highest-degree n's.
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{16n^3}{6n^3}$$
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{8}{3}$$
$$\frac{8}{3}$$

**Summation Properties**
$$\sum_{i=1}^n cf = c*\sum_{i=1}^n f$$
Where c is any constant
$$\sum_{i=1}^n c = cn $$
$$\sum_{i=1}^n f+g =\sum_{i=1}^nf + \sum_{i=1}^ng  $$
$$\sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} $$
$$\sum_{i=1}^n i^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^n i^3 = (\frac{n(n+1)}{2})^2$$

Comment: What is the summation property of $i^{2}$?

Comment: $\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$

Comment: OP asked for lower sum

Comment: @N.Bar - you offered to list some summation properties. If you don't mind, that would really help me out.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(i\Delta x)^2\Delta x=
(\Delta x)^3\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}i^2=\left(\dfrac2n\right)^3\dfrac{(n-1)n(2n-1)}{6}$$

Comment: Why is it $(i \Delta x)^{2}$ and not just $x^{2}$

Comment: Think of $i\Delta x$ as $x$.  As $i$ ranges from $0$ to $n$, $i\Delta x$ ranges from $0$ to $2$, with $\Delta x=\dfrac 2n$

Comment: Note:  $\dfrac{(n-1)n(2n-1)}{n^3}=\dfrac{2n^3-3n^2+n}{n^3}=2-\dfrac3n+\dfrac1{n^2}$